# Suppose that + subjunctive mood

Tags: subjunctives

I want to say: consider this hypothetical condition to be true.

> 1. Suppose that these two numbers are equal. (indicative)

> 2. Suppose that these two numbers be equal. (subjunctive)

Which one is correct?

Comment: Check out [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but+suppose+it+be%2Cbut+suppose+it+is%2Cbut+suppose+it+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20suppose%20it%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20suppose%20it%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20suppose%20it%20was%3B%2Cc0), showing that Simple Present/Past *but suppose it **is/was*** have always been far more common than "Subjunctive" *but suppose it **be***. All three are perfectly correct and usually mean exactly the same thing, so it's basically just a stylistic choice.

Comment: (But note just how far the subjunctive form has declined over the past couple of centuries. It might be "valid", but people will tend to notice it as being at the very least "old-fashioned", so I wouldn't normally recommend using it if you're unsure.)

Comment: I would not use "suppose that it be".  But I might well say "suppose that it were".  Of course, in your example - "Suppose that these two numbers were equal" - there is no distinct irrealis form.  Irrealis "were" is only distinct in the 1st and 3rd persons singular.